# GCC 5.4 linker error after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: c++, macos, qt, linker-errors, xcode8

Recently I updated to XCode Version 8.0 (8A218a) on El Capitan (OS X 10.11 using Macports 2.3.4), and ever since, I have been getting the following link error when I try to compile my project inside Qt Creator.

`/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-5 -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/zero/builds/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib -o uniMR.app/Contents/MacOS/uniMR ALL_OBJECT_FILES_GO_HERE.o   -F/Users/zero/builds/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -funit-at-a-time -fopenmp -lmlpack -larmadillo -framework CoreFoundation -DNDEBUG -lpthread -lALL_ITK_LIBS_GO_HERE -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework QtXml -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
**ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v2 file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [uniMR.app/Contents/MacOS/uniMR] Error 1**`

I am compiling the main project with gcc 5.4 (not clang) inside QtCreator (Qt 5.7), and all my dependent libraries (ITK, BOOST, etc) are compiled using gcc 5.4 as well. I also recompiled all my dependent libraries after upgrading XCode, but that did not help either. I could find only one post that is related to the error I am seeing, but it doesnt seem useful:
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/51701

All was fine before I upgraded XCode. Now I am not sure how to fix the issue. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

### UPDATE:

This doesnt seem like a problem with any of the external libraries I am linking with. This is what I did. I created a new "QT widgets application" in QtCreator, and chose to compile with gcc5. I get the same error `ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v2`. If I switch to clang, then there is no error.

Comment: I've not seen anything analogous to that. My bête noire change is that `dsymutil` behaves peculiarly if I create a (static) library and then update one of the members — it's OK when the library's first created, but not after it is updated, and it is only the updated members that give grief.  I've not yet got a MCVE for it.  The other problem is if I try a 32-bit build instead of a 64-bit build; then I get told about `warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated` — `.section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions` — `note: change section name to "__text"`.  (Home-built GCC 6.2.0.)

Comment: That's not a lot of help to you, but shows (a) not everyone has run into your specific problem, and (b) there may be other problems that you could still run into, and (c) some people have taken a look to see whether they can help.

Comment: Getting very similar errors: upgraded to xcode 8 (El Capitan 10.11.6) I'm using a couple C++ files in my ios project (.cpp / .hpp) now after upgrading, all of a sudden xcode is saying my CPP Header "#include <string>" 'string' file not found.  And if I comment that out it will then stop at the "class something" definition, "Did you mean 'Class'?"  So for some reason it stopped recognizing CPP.. I checked the CPP linker, and neither option, libc++ or libstdc++ has any effect

Answer (score 2):

I had this "ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v2" error building an unrelated project and was able to solve it by editing the .tbd file for the framework that was giving the error. 
For me that file was:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate.tbd
I simply removed the entire line "--- !tapi-tbd-v2" while building, and then put it back once finished.

Answer (score 1):

had yesterday the same problem. I had XCode 7.3 and 8 on my system. Removing 7.3 and moving 8 into the apps location solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I used macport's GCC 6 as compiler and linker. It seems the GCC doesn't understand the new tbd format. In the MacOSX SDK path, there are now only these tbd text files which contain info about the real dylib libraries. So I just symlinked the real libraries to the SDK paths beside their tbd files. Then GCC can directly use the real libraries without parsing tbd files.

Here is a script for creating those symlinks:
https://gist.github.com/michalfapso/9abdbd5669bfdc4cd1a2179824d299e9

Comment: I tried your script but am still getting the same error... gah. (trying to build gcc5 so I can later compile mingw64 gcc with it... *facepalm*)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while compiling with opam.

The workaround was `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`, thus `gcc` will resolve to the default `/usr/bin/gcc` which is `clang` on macOS.